# how does Chirp app implemented?

Tags: ios, audio

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chirp/id529469280?mt=8

Chirp is a magical new way to share your stuff – using sound. Chirp 'sings' information from one iPhone to another. Share photos, links, notes and more: all from your built-in iPhone speaker.

Does anyone know how it is implemented?

Comment: Based off of this line in the description, "Notes: you need to run Chirp to receive chirps. Sharing requires a network connection," I'm guessing this app doesn't actually transmit data using sound.

Answer (score 0):

Near Sound Data Transfer or a variation of.

http://www.tagattitude.fr/products/technology

Comment: Page not found.